# pandas 0.13 system error: cannot set thread affinity mask

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas, canopy, numexpr

this is my first stack overflow question so please pardon any ignorance about the forum on my part.

I am using python 2.7.6 64 bit and pandas 0.13.1-1 from Enthought Canopy 1.3.0.1715 on a win 7 machine. I have numpy 1.8.0-1 and numexpr 2.2.2-2.

I have inconsistent error behviour running the following on a pandas series of 10,000 numpy.float64 loaded from hdf:

```
import python
s = pandas.read_hdf(r'C:\test\test.h5', 'test')
s/2.
```

This gives me inconsistent behaviour, it sometimes works and sometimes throws:

```
OMP: Error #134: Cannot set thread affinity mask.
OMP: System error #87: The parameter is incorrect.
```

I have replicated this error on other machines, and the test case is derived from a unit test failure (with the above error) which was replicted on several machines and from a server. This has come up in an upgrade from pandas 0.12 to pandas 0.13.

The following consistantly runs with no error:

```
import python
s = pandas.read_hdf(r'C:\test\test.h5', 'test')
s.apply(lambda x: x/2.)
```

and,

```
import python
s = pandas.read_hdf(r'C:\test\test.h5', 'test')
pandas.computation.expressions.set_use_numexpr(False)
s/2.
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very similar problem to as described in this [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6720), and the linked [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3434)

It seems that only `canopy` is experiencing these issues. I think it has to do with the canopy numpy MKL build, but that is a guess as I have not been able to reproduce this. So here are some work-arounds:

- try to upgrade `numexpr` to 2.4 (current version), or downgrade to `2.1`
- try to use `numpy 1.8.1` via canopy
- try to install numpy/numexpr from the posted binaries [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/); I don't know exactly how canopy works so not sure if this is possible
- uninstall `numexpr`

you can also disable `numexpr` support via `pandas.computation.expressions.set_use_numexpr(False)`. Note that `numexpr` is REQUIRED in order to read/use HDF5 files via `PyTables`. However the expressions disabling of `numexpr` should just disable it for 'computations' (and not the HDF access).

Comment: Thanks Jeff, it sounds like this is a question for Enthought. I've been able to work around the problem for now by using `apply`, but am still concerned.